# Aceder de forma remota a mi computadora de casa

Tags: python, redes, ssh, vpn

Actualemente he intentado desde mi tableta compilar codigo en python, puedo realziarlo desde casa usando OpenSSH a mi equipo linux y tambien acceder a mi consola, me gustaria poder acceder de la misma forma fuera de mi red local.

De ser posible haciendo usao de OpenVPN, o de alguna forma que lo pueda configurar yo mismo, en un Equipo Linux Ubuntu 18.04, ya que hasta el momento no he podido encontrar una solucion debido a mi falta de conocimiento sobre el tema.

De ante mano muchas gracias por su atencion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:
vas a to router a advanced en `advance -> port forwarding` o redireccion de puerto
 en los nuevos modelos `advance -> nat forwarding -> virtual server`
en external port 22 `o el que deses es opcional`
en internal ip `el ip de tu pc`
en internal port 22 
protocol tcp

y ya podras acceder atraves de tu ip publica y el puerto que colocaste en external port
puedes verla en:
[mi ip](https://miip.es/)

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me servio esta informacion.

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción que se puede hacer es un ProxyJump a través de un servidor intermedio con una ip fija.

Aquí lo explico más a detalle:

[SSH desde un host con un usuario que usan varias personas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143141/ssh-desde-un-host-con-un-usuario-que-usan-varias-personas/218609#218609) ( ͡ ͡° ͜ ʖ ͡ ͡°)

En resumen, necesitas tres equipos, el equipo de donde te quieras conectar (la que vas a llevas a todos lados), un equipo con ip fija, el servidor a donde te quieres conectar (la computadora de tu casa).

Haces un port forwarding conectando las tres máquinas y de una te puedes conectar a otra, incluso si el firewall tiene restringido el acceso por algún puerto (que peligroso es SSH).

Answer (score 0):

Si es para algo personal. (no necesitas estabilidad 99%)

Puedes usar el servido serveo. (busca en google "serveo")
No hay que instalar nada ni configurar nada.

Solo hay que teclear dos comandos.

Según la info de la pagina. (lo he probado varias veces)

Comando a teclear en el tablet:

```
ssh -R Tablet_Luis_Olvera:22:localhost:22 serveo.net
```

Comando para acceder al tablet fuera de la red local.

```
ssh -J serveo.net usuarioTablet@Tablet_Luis_Olvera
```

En realidad estas creando un túnel inverso desde el tablet(-R) hacia el servidor serveo.net
Luego el servidor cuando accedes a su ip usando el subdominio "Tablet_Luis_Olvera" te redirige hacia dicho túnel inverso.

Evidentemente si la conexión ssh del tablet se cae pierdes el acceso.   (pero se puede usar autossh para crear una conexión mas estable).

Un saludo.